How transform a trial variational wave funtion to an appropriate ansatz for VQE?
I have a trial wave funtion as follows:
$$\psi_{trial}=e^{-\alpha r-\beta r^2}$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the variational parameters. It gives precise results for a specific system. Now I want to implement that system in Quantum computing framework using VQE algorithm. Although the most popular way to build an ansatz for a molecular system is HF wave function as reference state and UCCSD as a parametrized ansatz, I'm curious to know how can I map my good trial wave function to unitary gates (in qiskit)? Is it a good idea at all? Thanks in advance.
